# Only first input element inside div gets effected but not others

Tags: css, html, web

Here is my example from jdfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7RT7a/

Here is html code:

```
              <div id="product-pack">
                <div name="productRow">
                    <div class="product-title-input">
                        <p class="titles">Product</p>
                        <input name="product" type="text" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="unit-title-input">
                        <p class="titles">Unit</p>
                        <input name="unit" type="text" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="quality-title-input">
                        <p class="titles">Qty.</p>
                        <input name="qty" type="text" >
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is CSS:

```
.product-pack {
    float: left;
    width : 96%;
}

#product-pack input {
    width: 95%;
    height: 1em;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color:#CCC;
    border-color:#999;
    border-width:thin;
    padding: 1% 0 1% 0;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
}

#product-pack .product-title-input, .unit-title-input, .quality-title-input {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
} 

#product-pack .product-title-input {
    width: 82.5%;
    padding-top: 2%;
}
#product-pack .unit-title-input {
    width: 5%;
    padding: 2% 1.5% 0 0;
}
#product-pack .quality-title-input {
    width: 5%;
    padding-top: 2%;
}
```

In jsfiddle result, you can see that effect of #product-pack input CSS selector only applies to first input element inside #product-pack and no matter what I try, the other two input elements get no effect.

Am I missing something with CSS or HTML? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's being applied, but your other CSS is overriding it. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7RT7a/2/

Comment: Ok I get it but I want to specify width of all product, unit and quantity divs. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding percentages are calculated from the **width** of the containing block ([per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)).  Use `px` or `em` instead to specify the padding.

Comment: but problem still remains. As soon as I try to set width of .product-title-input, .quantity-title-input or .unit-title-input, height of input elements change.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Because when I look at your code and the rendered output, everything is rendered exactly how I expect. What do you expect to happen that isn't?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get all the input's to be the same height you have padding differences between the input's parents. specifically here,

```
#product-pack .unit-title-input {
width: 5%;
padding: 2% 1.5% 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `</input>` after `<input>`

[Jsfiddle -](http://jsfiddle.net/7RT7a/24/) as you can see here, all of the `<input>` boxes now are affected by the css styling (they turn yellow)

Comment: but I have no element with id "product-row" in my html.

Comment: no problem remains :( Your fiddle works but all divs containing input elements have same width which I dont want. I want different widths.

Comment: "#product-pack div div input{" has no effect when widths are set in last 3 css entries.

Comment: ok I updated the jsfiddle- changed back to `#product-pack .product-title-input` and the different widths now take effect.  The height difference of the `<input>`s is because of the width, if you set the first input's width to equal the others, the height becomes equal as well